# Función postgres regresa caracteres con comilla doble

Tags: sql, postgresql

La funcion en postgresql es la siguiente:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_sel_categoria(IN _nombre character varying)
RETURNS TABLE(acat_nombre character varying, acat_descrip character varying) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
IF _nombre = '' THEN
   return query 
   SELECT cat_nombre, cat_descrip
   FROM categoria
   order by cat_nombre;         
ELSE    
   return query 
   SELECT cat_nombre, cat_descrip
   FROM categoria
   WHERE cat_nombre like '%'|| _nombre||'%'
   order by cat_nombre; 

END IF; 
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100
ROWS 900001;
```

y retorna valores como los siguientes:

"15 AÑOS"

MATRIMONIO

BAUTIZO

"FIESTA INFANTIL"

Al realizar la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT cat_nombre, cat_descrip
FROM categoria
order by cat_nombre;
```

los valores retornados no contienen comillas dobles pero al ejecutar la función, esta me retorna valores con comillas dobles, específicamente como lo detalle en el listado anterior

Comment: ¿Qué herramienta usas para ejecutar la función y visualizar los resultados? Lo que describes me sorprende. Pero tal vez no tenga nada que ver con la base de datos en sí.

Comment: Estoy desarrollando en java y pensé que era problema de este lenguaje pero ya ejecute mi función en postgresql y me da el mismo resultado y es extraño porque solo pasa eso con 2 categorías, la de 15 años y la de fiesta infantil, no se si tenga algo que ver por caracteres especiales debido a que en la primera tiene una ñ  y en la otra un espacio en blanco

Comment: Solo un comentario: es interesante que los únicos valores que entrecomille son los que tienen espacios en el medio. Pareciera un comportamiento para poder exportar datos separados por espacios y no confundir estos textos como dos columnas.